# Query stop working after adding field

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure (I didn´t do it):

```
USE [RA_DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetLogWasteReport]    *******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLogWasteReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @IdLogWaste int,
    @initDate DateTime,
    @endDate DateTime
AS
BEGIN
SET FMTONLY OFF
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT lwd.Manifest
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN lwd.Manifest IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  lwd.Quantity END) AS TOTAL
  ,COUNT(lwd.Id) AS Count
  INTO #TEMPTotal
 FROM [dbo].[LogWaste] lw (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[LogWasteDetail] lwd (NOLOCK)
        ON lw.Id = lwd.IdLogWaste
--WHERE
--          lw.Id = @IdLogWaste
WHERE 
lwd.OutputDate IS NOT NULL
AND
lwd.IdWaste = @IdLogWaste
AND
lwd.OutputDate BETWEEN @initDate AND @endDate
 GROUP BY lwd.Manifest



 SELECT
    w.Name AS Waste
    ,a.Description AS Area
    ,lwd.Quantity
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),lwd.InitDate,101) AS InitDate
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),lwd.OutputDate,101) AS OutputDate
    ,lwd.Balance
    ,lwd.Manifest
    ,temp.TOTAL
    ,temp.Count
    FROM [dbo].[LogWaste] lw (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[LogWasteDetail] lwd (NOLOCK)
        ON lw.Id = lwd.IdLogWaste
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Waste] w (NOLOCK)
        ON lwd.IdWaste = w.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Area] a (NOLOCK)
        ON a.Id = lwd.IdArea
    INNER JOIN #TEMPTotal temp 
        ON lwd.Manifest = temp.Manifest OR (lwd.Manifest IS NULL AND temp.Manifest IS NULL)
     --WHERE
        --  lw.Id = @IdLogWaste
    WHERE 
        lwd.OutputDate IS NOT NULL
        AND
        lwd.IdWaste = @IdLogWaste
        AND
        lwd.OutputDate BETWEEN @initDate AND @endDate
    ORDER BY lwd.Manifest,lwd.InitDate 


   DROP TABLE #TEMPTotal



END
```

That I want to do is to add field "BranchOfficeId" that I can get from [LogWaste] (there is BranchOfficeIdFk), what I need
to do to select this one in this store?
I try something like

```
USE [SA_DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetLogWasteReport]  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLogWasteReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @IdLogWaste int,
    @initDate DateTime,
    @endDate DateTime,
    @branchOfficeId Int
AS
BEGIN
SET FMTONLY OFF
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT lwd.Manifest
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN lwd.Manifest IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  lwd.Quantity END) AS TOTAL
  ,COUNT(lwd.Id) AS Count
  INTO #TEMPTotal
 FROM [dbo].[LogWaste] lw (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[LogWasteDetail] lwd (NOLOCK)
        ON lw.Id = lwd.IdLogWaste
--WHERE
--          lw.Id = @IdLogWaste
WHERE 
lwd.OutputDate IS NOT NULL
AND
lwd.IdWaste = @IdLogWaste
AND
lwd.OutputDate BETWEEN @initDate AND @endDate
 GROUP BY lwd.Manifest



 SELECT
    w.Name AS Waste
    ,a.Description AS Area
    ,lwd.Quantity
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),lwd.InitDate,101) AS InitDate
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),lwd.OutputDate,101) AS OutputDate
    ,lwd.Balance
    ,lwd.Manifest
    ,lw.BranchOfficeId
    ,temp.TOTAL
    ,temp.Count
    FROM [dbo].[LogWaste] lw (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[LogWasteDetail] lwd (NOLOCK)
        ON lw.Id = lwd.IdLogWaste
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Waste] w (NOLOCK)
        ON lwd.IdWaste = w.Id
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Area] a (NOLOCK)
        ON a.Id = lwd.IdArea
    INNER JOIN #TEMPTotal temp 
        ON lwd.Manifest = temp.Manifest OR (lwd.Manifest IS NULL AND temp.Manifest IS NULL)
     --WHERE
        --  lw.Id = @IdLogWaste
    WHERE 
        lwd.OutputDate IS NOT NULL
        AND
        lw.BranchOfficeId = @branchOfficeId
        AND
        lwd.IdWaste = @IdLogWaste
        AND
        lwd.OutputDate BETWEEN @initDate AND @endDate
    ORDER BY lwd.Manifest,lwd.InitDate 


   DROP TABLE #TEMPTotal



END
```

But it didn´t work, my query always returns value 0, can anyone help me?

Query(before):

```
result = context.GetLogWasteReport(id, initDate, endDate).ToList();
```

Query(after):

```
result = context.GetLogWasteReport(id, initDate, endDate, branchOfficeId).ToList();
```

Note: before I add field branchOfficeId query works and get values

Answer (score 0):

I bet your `@branchOfficeId` is not getting properly set and is coming over as 0. I would make sure it is set to what you think it is being set to.

If your intent to allow a value of zero to indicate no selection then simply update your  where clause like so.

```
(@branchOfficeId=0 OR lw.BranchOfficeId = @branchOfficeId)
```

If allowing null...

```
(@branchOfficeId IS NULL OR lw.BranchOfficeId = @branchOfficeId)
```

Comment: But the value is not null, Waste table have value in every branchOfficeId, why it can came null?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting no results because there are no matches.  This is probably because  value is `NULL`.

If this is the problem, you can fix it with:

```
   (lw.BranchOfficeId = @branchOfficeId or @branchOfficeId is NULL)
```

Comment: But the value is not null, Waste table have value in every branchOfficeId, why it can came null?

Comment: Do you have the source code of the calling service? I suggest that you set a breakpoint on this line --> result = context.GetLogWasteReport(id, initDate, endDate, branchOfficeId).ToList(); and then trace as far as you can into your data calls. There is probally a missing mapping somewhere between layers.